# Правильно ли говорить "Я интерпретирую запах" в контексте я "слышу" запах, определяю, чую? Речь не идет о профессиональном действии

Tags: грамотная-речь

правильно ли говорить "Я интерпретирую запах" в контексте я "слышу" запах, определяю, чую?  Речь не идет о профессиональном  действии, где уместно сказать классифицирую или интерпретирую. Просто в обиходе.

Comment: Интерпретирую, классифицирую — в обиходе? Кудряво.

Comment: Запах обычно *чувствуют*. *Слышать* и *чуять* - это просторечное (если речь о людях, а не о животных), а *определять* имеет другой смысл, сходный с *интерпретировать*.

Answer (score 1):

В контексте *простой фиксации* явления (здесь - запаха), без последующей конкретизации, так сказать нельзя: **интерпретация** означает субъективное *истолкование* (объяснение) или *трактовку* чего-либо, раскрытие внутренней сути явления по внешнему признаку и т. п. После упоминания об интерпретации обычно следует её конкретизация (интерпретировал как что, как именно и т. п.). Применительно к *интерпретации запаха* возможна такая ситуация:

> В разговоре с товарищами по охоте я **интерпретировал** этот **запах** *как*
>   *признак* близости прошедшего тигра, пометившего территорию.

Практический пример из журнала:

> Полученные данные свидетельствуют, что люди с более подвижной нервной
>   системой склонны **интерпретировать** [незнакомые] **запахи** *как*
>   *положительные*... (Запахи как фактор, влияющий на скрытую агрессию -
>   Психология и право - 2012. № 3)